I'm trying to write a middleware in Nestjs using javascript
but something is going wrong.I'm getting a typo. can yo help me?
app.module
export class AppModule extends NestMiddleware {
   configure(consumer) {
      consumer
        .apply(ApiTokenCheckMiddleware)
        .forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
      }
   }

middleware
import { NestMiddleware } from "../../../node_modules/@nestjs/common/index";

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.headers);
});   


I will pull the headers with middleware

Why are you mixing NestJs with ExpressJs?

What kind of error you get?

I shared the error as a comment

throw err;
nest-container  |     ^
nest-container  |
nest-container  | SyntaxError: /app/src/app.module.js: Identifier 

'AppModule' has already been declared. (26:13)
nest-container  |
nest-container  |   24 |   providers: [AppService],
nest-container  |   25 | })
nest-container  | > 26 | export class AppModule extends NestMiddleware {
nest-container  |      |              ^
nest-container  |   27 |   configure(consumer) {
nest-container  |   28 |     consumer
nest-container  |   29 |       .apply(ApiTokenCheckMiddleware)
code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
nest-container  |   reasonCode: 'VarRedeclaration',
nest-container  |   loc: Position { line: 26, column: 13, index: 874 },
nest-container  |   pos: 874
nest-contair  |
nest-container  | Node.js v20.12.2
nest-container  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before
starting...

I fixed some bugs but i get that bug now
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
nest-container  | Require stack:
nest-container  | - /app/src/auth/middleware/api.token.check.middleware.js
nest-container  | - /app/src/app.module.js
nest-container  | - /app/src/main.js
nest-container  | - /app/index.js
